# HTML5 Notifications Usage

Tags: angularjs, html, notifications, html5-notifications

I have an angular real-time messaging application and I wanted to use HTML5 notifications. I tried the following inside my controller:

```
$rootScope.$on("message_recieved", function(event, data) {
  new Notification(data.sender_name, {
    body: data.body, icon: data.avatar, dir:'auto'
  });
}
```

and

```
$rootScope.$on("server_offline", function(event, data) {
  new Notification("Offline", {
    body: "You are offline. Refresh your page now.", dir:'auto'
  });
}
```

The notifications are not showing. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Did you [grant the permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are not permitted to display Notifications.  You can request permission:

```
$rootScope.$on( 'message_received', function(event, data){
     Notification.requestPermission(function (permission){
          if (permission === "granted"){
               new Notification(data.sender_name, {
                    body: data.body, icon: data.avatar, dir:'auto'
               })
          }
      })
 })
```

src - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: I knew about the permission thing but they were not `granted` because I am developing two applications running on `localhost:9000` and I denied one of them which neglected the other. Also you do not have to check if permission is `granted` or no, you can initialize the notification and it will not be shown if not granted. Thanks though.